# Access denied when uploading S3 Objects

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm following [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album.html) tutorial of adding/listing objects from S3.

At first, I had problem to list objects because of `Access Denied` error, so I found that I have to to add additional permission `s3:ListBucket` and resource `arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket` to the role created by **cognito to unauth user**:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, when I try to upload a file, I'm getting another `Access Denied`.

Am I doing something wrong or this tutorial has so many errors?

Additional Checks:

- bucket has CORS
- **I didn't change any permissions of bucket after creating it (everything default)**
- I'm using proper Cognito Identity Pool ID ( I can list albmus )
- I can delete album
- After `Access Denied` error I can see that there is new identity in cognito unauth, so script works properly.
- Owner of the bucket (me) has read/write access to the bucket

Comment: have checked the user IAM permissions? Also what do you use to upload a file, `multer` ?

Comment: @someonewithakeyboard I'm just using Java's spring boot application to serve static files, the code and everything is directly from the linked tutorial - just the html page with added scripts in another file.

Comment: Try adding `s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads` and `s3:PutObjectAcl` in your `Action` list.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how cognito works internally and it might be playing with the ACL of the s3 object. So, adding `s3:PutObjectAcl` and `s3:GetObjectAcl` operations access might help. Additionally, if your code is doing multipart uploads to S3, you should consider adding `s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads` operation access. `s3:PutObject` operation already adds the permissions for **Initiate Multipart Upload**, **Upload Part**, **Complete Multipart Upload**.

Comment: Nothing works for me, I gave full access to cognito unauth role and it still doesn't work. I'm starting to think what I did wrong, maybe I will start from 0. Are you aware about giving additional permissions to bucket itself? I didn't touch them and tutorial mentioned `Make sure you have both Read and Write permissions on Objects.`

Comment: I've used cognito service for s3 download as the android client wouldn't allow multipart downloading without it. But, in my case, the bucket was public and that's why we didn't face any issues. We didn't have any issues with making the bucket public. Have you tried modifying the bucket access to public?

Comment: This would make sense, but I expected that cognito unauth role is a kind of user that can have access without setting bucket to public. Do you think there is any explanation that I can create folders (putObject) but can't add files (ManagedUpload)?

Comment: in my case its worked thx

Answer (score 1):

the below sample policy works for me.

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
      {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl"
         ],
         "Resource": [            
            "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME",
            "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: I have implemented this policy but still had: `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the UploadPart operation: Access Denied`, but my working bucket is not on AWS, and I' am only working with `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`

Having `--no-sign-request` flag on `aws s3 cp` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add IAM role with the policy, this will enable the user to upload any file with API or by the console.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "1",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::777777:user/myuser"
                 ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*",
                "arn:aws:s3::: bucketname"
            ]
        }
}
```

Comment: Not sure, If I understand this config properly, but I don't want to give access to AWS user, but to user from cognito identity pool, that is why I attached this role to unauth cognito user.

Comment: I guess you can use cognito identity pool ARN instead of user ARN.

Comment: Actually this role is assigned directly to unauth user of cognito, so it should work, and looking at cognito identiy pool activity I hit it as unauth user.